# How to close a popup when another popup is open using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm working on a Python/Django web application, and I don't have much knowledge of JavaScript yet. The answers I've googled suggest a bit of a different approach, and I can't adjust those solutions to my code due to my yet little knowledge of JS. Will be grateful for helping me out. Thanks in advance!

So, I have a few popup windows, which have different IDs and they're all opened and closed with the same two JavaScript functions by passing thir IDs as a $target variable. I also want to close any opened popup window if another popup is opened by the user, so only one can be opened at the same time, and also close a popup window if the user clicks a glyphicon button (the same that opened that popup window with the first click).

Here's my code:
**html template**

```
<script>
function popup($target) {
      document.getElementById($target).style.display = "block";
}

function closepopup($target) {
      document.getElementById($target).style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Example of where these functions are called (same template):

```
<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="popup('add')" style="position: absolute; right: 2%; bottom: 10%; padding: 6px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> <div class="form-popup popupfont" id="add-important">
      <form action="{% url 'add-general' %}" method="post" class="form-container">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="task_text">Add a task:</label>
            <input type="text" id="task_text" name="task">
            <input type="date" id="time" name="datestr" value="{{ date }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="important">
            <input type="hidden" name="datestr" value="{{ date }}">
            <br><br><p><input type="submit" class="formbutton" name="Send" value="Send" onclick="closepopup('add')">
      </form>
      <button class="formbutton gray" style="font-size: 1.0em;" onclick="closepopup('add')">  <span>Back</span></button> </div>
```

**css file**

```
/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  width: 500px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #5f788a;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #B0C4DE;
}

.popupfont {
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;

}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a reference to the last opened popup element. When opening a new popup, close the already opened one via it's reference and save the new element as reference. Something like this should work:

```
var lastOpenedPopup = null;

function popup($target) {
  var targetEl = document.getElementById($target); // get element
  targetEl.style.display = "block";                // show element
  if (lastOpenedPopup) {                           // another popup visible?
    closepopup(lastOpenedPopup);                   // then close!
  }
  lastOpenedPopup = targetEl;                      // save element reference
}

function closepopup($target) {
  var targetEl = document.getElementById($target); // get element
  targetEl.style.display = "none";                 // hide element
  lastOpenedPopup = null;                          // unset reference!
}
```